# Is mixing Wordpress and MEAN-Stack a practical Idea?

Tags: wordpress, angular, mean-stack, user-management

*tltr: 
Wordpress-plugin for Usermanagement and Angular2/MEAN-Stack for content?*

I wrote an Angular2-App on a MEAN-Stack with is running locally on my machine right now.
I run my webserver on localhost:3000 with Node.js, the Angular2-App is getting its Data (Numbers and Averages etc.) from the MongoDB.

Some Day I want to make the App public and have parts of it as paid content. I am not sure how to handle the User-Data. For me it does not seem to be a good idea to have the userdata on the same MongoDB as my content for the app.

- Is using a Wordpress-Site with a professional plugin for usermanagement and just put my App behind the Paywall a way to do go?
- Or should I avoid mixing WP and MEAN at all?
- Can I use WP for a Startingpage while the Angular2-App loads?